# Set column to only accept negative values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, constraint, azure-vm

Is there anyway to change a column data type so that it will accept only negative values?

It's SQL Server 2014 Azure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE t ( n INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (n < 0) );
```

works in most RDBMS I know.

**Edit:** A comment by @IMSop prompts me to specify why I wrote “*most* RDMS I know:” it is well known (and very unfortunate) that `CHECK` constraints [aren’t honored by MySQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working) In MySQL, you have to use [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) instead. Another option is to switch to MariaDB.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved (at least in Sql Server) by using a [CHECK](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) constraint.

From the above post:

> CHECK constraints enforce domain integrity by limiting the values that
>   are accepted by one or more columns. You can create a CHECK constraint
>   with any logical (Boolean) expression that returns TRUE or FALSE based
>   on the logical operators. For example, the range of values for a
>   salary column can be limited by creating a CHECK constraint that
>   allows for only data that ranges from $15,000 through $100,000. This
>   prevents salaries from being entered beyond the regular salary range.
>   The logical expression would be the following: salary >= 15000 AND
>   salary <= 100000.